# Submitting google form using a javascript script

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-forms

I am trying to create a quiz platform for students based on google forms. So i basically embedded the google form as an iframe in my site and would like to start a timer and if the timer finished, the form should be submitted automatically.

I know that I can call a function in the iframe using this code
`document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.targetFunction();`

However, I need to know the function that gets called when the submit button is pressed

Comment: "I know that I can call a function in the iframe using this code" — You can't. It would be a security violation.

Comment: without "co-operation" ... cross site iframes are isolated - so, what you "know" is in fact, not possible, as is the part you want to know